# Storing strings that appear after a word in a document into arrays and combining them

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, text-files

I have a file, which, among other data, has the following lines:

```
group = A_1
group_sub = A101,A102,A103,A104
group = A_2
group_sub = A201,A202,A203,A204,A205,A206
```

A1 is males, and A2 are females.
I need to read in the file, and each time it reaches the word "group", store the name of the group (for example, A_1) in an array. 
Then move on to the next line and store the subjects in the group as another array [A101,A102,A103,A104].
And then i need to merge the name of the group with subjects in the group for males and for females like so:

```
[A_1,A101,A102,A103,A104] (for males)
[A_2,A201,A202,A203,A204,A205,A206] (for females)
```

My code:

```
public class Test {
    File fromFile = new File(filename);         
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String[]groupTitle = null;
        String[]groupSubjects = null;
        if (line.startsWith("group")){  
            String[] title = line.split("= ");                
            groupTitle= title[1].split(" ");
          //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groupTitle));
        }
            if (line.startsWith("group_sub")){
                 String[] names = line.split("= ");   
                 groupSubjects= names[1].split(", "); 
                // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groupSubjects));
            }

            String[] both = new String[groupTitle.length + groupSubjects.length];
            System.arraycopy(groupTitle, 0, both, 0, groupSubjects.length);
            System.arraycopy(groupSubjects, 0, both, groupTitle.length, groupSubjects.length);
}
}
```

At the moment, from within the loop it prints out :

```
[A_1]
[A101,A102,A103,A104]
[A_2]
[A201,A202,A203,A204,A205,A206]
```

When I try to merge the arrays, they return empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code what we need to do is first for `group` and than for `group_sub` so we have to merge arrays after `group_sub`.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.startsWith("group")&&line.contains(",")==false){  
                String[] title = line.split("= ");                
                groupTitle= title[1].split(" ");
          // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groupTitle));

            }
               if (line.startsWith("group_sub")){
                     String[] names = line.split("= ");   
                     groupSubjects= names[1].split(", "); 
               //    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groupSubjects));

                     if(groupTitle!=null&&groupSubjects!=null){
                      String[] both = new String[groupTitle.length + groupSubjects.length];
                       System.arraycopy(groupTitle, 0, both, 0, groupSubjects.length);
                      System.arraycopy(groupSubjects, 0, both, groupTitle.length, groupSubjects.length);
                      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(both));
                       }
                }


}
```

This will give Output like this

```
[A_1, A101,A102,A103,A104]
[A_2, A201,A202,A203,A204,A205,A206]
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't react to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(both));`

Comment: yes, i did. I even thought there was some problem with the brackets, but it wasn't that...

Comment: Ok, i found my mistake - my `String[]groupTitle = null;
        String[]groupSubjects = null;` was inside the while loop. However, when I put it outside the loop, it does seem to merge, but prints each array out many many times.

Comment: Same thing happened when i tried and i put last three statements inside secone if as stated in my answer.

Comment: yes, now I moved the if loop and it works! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

On your first `arraycopy()` call, you assign the number of components to be copied as `groupSubjects.length` but you want to copy `groupTitle` array into array `both`.

So if you change

`System.arraycopy(groupTitle, 0, both, 0, groupSubjects.length);`

to

`System.arraycopy(groupTitle, 0, both, 0, groupTitle.length);`

it will first add `groupTitle` array to `both` array. After that your second statement will append `groupSubjects` array to `both` array and your arrays will be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class Test {
    File fromFile = new File("Data.txt");         
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fromFile));
for ( String line = br.readLine() ; line !=null;line=br.readLine())
{
    String[]groupTitle = null;
    String[]groupSubjects = null;
    System.out.println ( line );
    if (line.startsWith("group"))
    {  
        String[] title = line.split("= ");                
        groupTitle= title[1].split(" ");
      //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groupTitle));
    } 
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line.startsWith("group_sub"))
    {
            System.out.println ( line );
            String[] names = line.split("= ");
             System.out.println ( names.length );
             groupSubjects= names[1].split(", "); 
//             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(groupSubjects));
    }
        String[] both = new String[groupTitle.length + groupSubjects.length];
        System.arraycopy(groupTitle, 0, both, 0, groupTitle.length);
        System.arraycopy(groupSubjects, 0, both, groupTitle.length, groupSubjects.length);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(both));
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I get a null pointer exception at `String[] both = new String[groupTitle.length + groupSubjects.length];`

Comment: I have tested this program.In your program you have make one mistake first you are reading the group and then you are not reading the next line so the value of groupSubjects.length will be null. That is the reason you are getting the null pointer exception.